Error when deploying Django/DRF backend on Google Cloud: No matching distribution found for Django==5.0.4
I am trying to deploy my Django backend (using Django Rest Framework) on a Google Cloud VM instance. However, when I run pip install -r requirements.txt, I encounter the following error:
Collecting asgiref==3.8.1
  Using cached asgiref-3.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting attrs==23.2.0
  Using cached attrs-23.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==5.0.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 1.4.21, 1.4.22, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 1.5.12, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8a1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 1.8.14, 1.8.15, 1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.8.19, 1.9a1, 1.9b1, 1.9rc1, 1.9rc2, 1.9, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 1.9.10, 1.9.11, 1.9.12, 1.9.13, 1.10a1, 1.10b1, 1.10rc1, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.10.7, 1.10.8, 1.11a1, 1.11b1, 1.11rc1, 1.11, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.11.6, 1.11.7, 1.11.8, 1.11.9, 1.11.10, 1.11.11, 1.11.12, 1.11.13, 1.11.14, 1.11.15, 1.11.16, 1.11.17, 1.11.18, 1.11.20, 1.11.21, 1.11.22, 1.11.23, 1.11.24, 1.11.25, 1.11.26, 1.11.27, 1.11.28, 1.11.29, 2.0a1, 2.0b1, 2.0rc1, 2.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9, 2.0.10, 2.0.12, 2.0.13, 2.1a1, 2.1b1, 2.1rc1, 2.1, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.7, 2.1.8, 2.1.9, 2.1.10, 2.1.11, 2.1.12, 2.1.13, 2.1.14, 2.1.15, 2.2a1, 2.2b1, 2.2rc1, 2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.5, 2.2.6, 2.2.7, 2.2.8, 2.2.9, 2.2.10, 2.2.11, 2.2.12, 2.2.13, 2.2.14, 2.2.15, 2.2.16, 2.2.17, 2.2.18, 2.2.19, 2.2.20, 2.2.21, 2.2.22, 2.2.23, 2.2.24, 2.2.25, 2.2.26, 2.2.27, 2.2.28, 3.0a1, 3.0b1, 3.0rc1, 3.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.0.4, 3.0.5, 3.0.6, 3.0.7, 3.0.8, 3.0.9, 3.0.10, 3.0.11, 3.0.12, 3.0.13, 3.0.14, 3.1a1, 3.1b1, 3.1rc1, 3.1, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.1.4, 3.1.5, 3.1.6, 3.1.7, 3.1.8, 3.1.9, 3.1.10, 3.1.11, 3.1.12, 3.1.13, 3.1.14, 3.2a1, 3.2b1, 3.2rc1, 3.2, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3, 3.2.4, 3.2.5, 3.2.6, 3.2.7, 3.2.8, 3.2.9, 3.2.10, 3.2.11, 3.2.12, 3.2.13, 3.2.14, 3.2.15, 3.2.16, 3.2.17, 3.2.18, 3.2.19, 3.2.20, 3.2.21, 3.2.22, 3.2.23, 3.2.24, 3.2.25, 4.0a1, 4.0b1, 4.0rc1, 4.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.0.6, 4.0.7, 4.0.8, 4.0.9, 4.0.10, 4.1a1, 4.1b1, 4.1rc1, 4.1, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.1.3, 4.1.4, 4.1.5, 4.1.6, 4.1.7, 4.1.8, 4.1.9, 4.1.10, 4.1.11, 4.1.12, 4.1.13, 4.2a1, 4.2b1, 4.2rc1, 4.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 4.2.5, 4.2.6, 4.2.7, 4.2.8, 4.2.9, 4.2.10, 4.2.11, 4.2.12, 4.2.13, 4.2.14, 4.2.15, 4.2.16)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Django==5.0.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))

Here are the steps I performed
cd Project_Backend
python3 -m venv env
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
python3 -m venv env
source ./env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt

That's my requirements.txt
asgiref==3.8.1
attrs==23.2.0
Django==5.0.4
django-cors-headers==4.4.0
djangorestframework==3.15.1
drf-spectacular==0.27.2
inflection==0.5.1
jsonschema==4.22.0
jsonschema-specifications==2023.12.1
PyYAML==6.0.1
referencing==0.35.1
rpds-py==0.18.1
sqlparse==0.4.4
typing_extensions==4.11.0
tzdata==2024.1
uritemplate==4.1.1

I am running Ubuntu on my Google Cloud VM. How should I resolve this issue and successfully deploy my Django application?

Please don't include screenshots in questions when it would be trivial to copy-paste the text output. Image content is less easy to use when responding, reduces accessibility and the the image may not outlive the question.

The error suggests (!) that your Python runtime isn't able to access Django 5.x (the most recent versions listed in the error are 4.x). Django 5.x requires Python 3.10+ (see release notes). What version of Python 3.x is installed (python --version)?

@DazWilkin These are my Python and Pip versions: Python 3.8.10 and pip 20.0.2 .
When I execute sudo apt install python3.11 in the shell, then I get this error: "Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.10
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.10'"

what happens if you run sudo apt update followed by sudo apt install python3 python3-dev python3-venv python3-pip? This should install the latest version of python3.

Official doc for the commands shared by @Edo Akse.
As last resort, perform a full uninstall/install of your Python3 & pip in case the installation is defective:
sudo apt-get remove python3-pip
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip install pip==24.2
If you don’t have a specific need for Django v5.0.4, try using the latest  version 5.1.2 (October 8, 2024).

Provide the full requirements.txt and Python version you plan to use to run the code.
The errors indicate that PIP cannot install the version requested in the requirements.txt file as it conflicts with other requirements or is not supported by the Python version you have installed.
If you are running something you didn't author, then your best bet is to install the Python version that the code was intended to run using the specified dependency versions frozen in the text file.
Alternatively, you can go error-by-error and upgrade each dependency to the next supported version or go the opposite route and upgrade to the latest supported version for each. Dependency resolution can be tricky if you don't know which features of which dependency are being used, as things get deprecated, so using the correct versions helps.
For Django, you can try removing the "==5.0.4" part from the requirements and see if PIP can find a compatible version for your project. You may need to do this one dependency at a time until you get it running.
Look into PipEnv and Poetry, which help simplify dependency management.

I added the requirements.txt in my question post.

It would help to share the Python version (3.x.x). You can find this by opening the terminal and typing in python3 --version - the output will tell you which version you have installed. Based on the Django==5.0.4, you need a Python runtime installed that is version >= 3.10. Here are some Ubuntu specific steps.
